# Code replacement macro in haxe?

Tags: macros, haxe

How do you replace all occurrences of `fun` with `function` without turning things like `function` into `functionction` obviously.
How would I go about eliminating the need for `return` when using `fun`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can introduce new keywords with macros, you have to use somehow valid syntax which you can transform to other valid syntax.

> A basic macro is a syntax-transformation. It receives zero or more expressions and also returns an expression. If a macro is called, it effectively inserts code at the place it was called from. In that respect, it could be compared to a preprocessor like #define in C++, but a Haxe macro is not a textual replacement tool.
>
> **Source:** [macro in the Haxe manual](https://haxe.org/manual/macro.html)

Comment: I am pretty sure (80%) that `fun` is a valid expression. It means lookup the  value of the member/field appropriated with the identifier `fun`.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is with the `(a : A, b : B, c : C)` part cause that is not an expression I'm familiar with. It would be nice to be able to generate small functions without parameters if that's all that is possible.

Comment: This is great: https://github.com/ciscoheat/slambda/blob/master/src/Slambda.hx
It uses `fn` which is close enough but I can't make sense of the code.

Comment: `fn` there isn't a new invented keyword (what you want), but an actual function.

Comment: How does this: https://github.com/deltaluca/goodies/blob/master/goodies/Lambdas.hx
work?
It has a function called `replace`, how is it used? I understand the trick there is doing some work with the arrow binary op but it's not clear how it's applied to the code.

Comment: Every expression inside any function-body in any class that implements interface Lambas (because of the autoBuild metadata) will be replaced by what the macro `replace` function does. It replaces map-comprehension syntax to translate those expressions to functions. 

It does not introduce new keywords nor operators, it just translates valid Haxe syntax `[key => value, otherkey => value]` to other syntax.

You could do some thing like that, but instead of `fun`, use metadata, like `@:fun(1 + 2)` and search for any metadata like that. I'm not sure where you are heading at.

Comment: I want a readable way to express functions with no parameters without having to type function and return like in: `function() return xyx;`. I just like to write a lot of small functions (that don't mutate state), it may accidentally introduce some code duplication but it allows me to ensure I don't change existing functionality by adding new features. Writing `function` and `return` clutters this code.

I am considering a syntax highly similar to Slambda but my main goal was gaining a sound understanding of the way such a thing is implemented. Your help and Juraj's made it clear to me.